# React native - how can I save the result of my fields

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-native, input, storage

i have my app like this : https://i.gyazo.com/4cfe178d3a59bf4e7449a7aacd0f114e.png
It is a app for play to a drinking game :p. I want to save all of input already the four input and before and after the fields that the user has added

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { style } from './style';

class Form extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    StatusBar.setBarStyle('light-content', true);
    console.log(this.props);
    state = {
        users: [{
            id:1,
            prenom:''
        }, {
            id:2,
            prenom:''
        }, {
            id:3,
            prenom:''
        }, {
            id:4,
            prenom:''
        }]
    }
  }

  saveUser = value => {
    console.log('test');
  };

  showInput() {
    return state.users.map((item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return (
            <TextInput
                key={item.id}
                style={style.input}
                placeholder={`Prénom ${item.id}`}
                placeholderTextColor="#29235c"
                />
        );
    });
   }

  render() {
    return this.props.fontLoaded ? (
      <View style={style.bgWhite}>
        <ScrollView>
            {
                 this.showInput()
            }
          <View style={style.morePlayer}>
            <Text style={style.morePlayerText}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <View style={style.center}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            activeOpacity={0.9}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Game')}
            style={style.btnPlay}
          >
            <Text style={style.textPlay}>ON TEASE!</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <Button title="Go to Details" onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Game')} />
        </View>
      </View>
    ) : null;
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Should I save this in the asyncstorage ? I want to pass the all value of input in the params to go in other screen.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered using a state management solution like redux?

Comment: Yes, I will use it but for keep all the data of input, how i can do ?

Comment: What do you mean by keeping the data? are you talking about session storage? or do you mean that this data should be saved for the next usage of the app? i.g: that app was killed and reopened?
If you only need session storage (meaning data that will be available as long as the app is open) then redux is the complete solution, otherwise you would have to have a local database in the app, there are a lot of different local db solutions, you could technically use LocalStorage, but if you are going to save a lot of info, that's just not gonna cut it, take a look at [Realm.io](https://realm.io/)

Comment: i only need session storage so redux its the solution for that, now if i want to recover the value of the fields when i press on the button, I created an array with my 4 predefined fields and I made a loop with map to display them but I'm blocking on passing the values of the fields in my array..

Comment: Well if you are using redux then you just need to create a `reducer` that will swap the information you need upon the button click, so if you have an array with values, you can have two arrays, one will be for the current list and another one for the next list

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to pass the params to another screen you can just pass an object as the second argument of navigate.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Game', {
    users: this.state.users,
    otherParam: 'anything you want here',
});
```

Comment: Yes for that, I had seen a solution like this, my real problem its for keep the data of all input when i press on the button